# How to limit maximum line in log file

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu, logging, tee

Given a bash script running `ping -c 25 google.com | tee /home/user/myLogFile.log`

And the output file `/home/user/myLogFile.log` containing:

```
PING google.com (117.102.117.238) 56(84) bytes of data. 
64 bytes from 117.102.117.238: icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from 117.102.117.238: icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=61.1 ms
(...)
64 bytes from 117.102.117.238: icmp_seq=25 ttl=61 time=7.11 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
25 packets transmitted, 25 received, 0% packet loss, time 24038ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.573/11.293/61.102/11.210 ms
```

How to limit the maximum lines in the log file, and if that maximum is reached, the file is reset and keep the next output saved?

Comment: thank you S.Spieker, I already use that link before.
But, its not working like I wanted. 
the script like `my_program | dd bs=1 count=100 > log` just make the file until 100 Bytes and not resume the 'my_program'  

regards

Comment: Actually, there is `my_program | tee >(split -d -b 100000 -)` as accepted answer in the above suggested duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think you can do something like:

```
ping -c 25 google.com | tee >(split -d -b 100000 - /home/user/myLogFile.log)
```

Comment: I just tried that script but seems any error ->
>tutak@127:~$ ping -c 25 google.com | sudo tee >(split -d -b 100000     myLogFile.log)

>tee: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory

I have create the file manualy but still error
regards

Comment: I forgot the '-' - please try again

Comment: @MuhammadJendroYuwono you cannot add a "sudo" here in the command.